# Understanding of the command "apt show"

Tags: apt

Usually I use the command `apt show pkg_name` to check the description of a package. For example, `apt show apache2`. I just found that I can use `apt info pkg_name` to do the same thing. But I can't find this in the document (`man 8 apt`), from which I can find the `apt show` command. Is `apt info` undocumented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `apt info` is undocumented. It was added [as an alias for `show`](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/commit/a55221a856f44cf71ea3e0603844698ecde8ec28) to help users used to `dnf info`, `snap info` etc., following [this pull request](https://github.com/Debian/apt/pull/76).